# how to edit quantity in cart with ajax magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax

I'd like to know how to **change the quantity** of a product on front using **ajax** ?

When I change the quantity in the input and them click on the small pencil to apply modification, I'm redirected to the page of the product.

How do I change that ?